# Office 365 API - create folder bug and PUT file "content-length"

Tags: ms-office, office365

### Creating folder issue

Creating new subfolder with the same name as parent folder error

Here is my request:
`PUT {base-url}/Files/getByPath('/Bug/Bug')` - fails with 409, "NameAlreadyExists"

But, this will work:
`PUT {base-url}/Files/getByPath('/Bug/Bug/Bug2')`

**NOTICE**: There is no folder /Bug/Bug, before each test request I am removing this folder

Here is my video for this bug: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NknDvL1rVsM&feature=youtu.be

### Content length issue

Request:
`GET {base-url}/Files/getByPath('/Some.pdf')/content`
There is no "content-length" header in response headers. Why?

### SUMMARY:

1. Can't create folder /Bug/Bug or /Foo/Foo or /New/New or /Foo/Bar/Foo
2. Cannot get "content-length" when downloading file through API

Comment: He he. Also you can try to `PUT {base-url}/Files/getByPath('/foo3/foo/bar/foo3')` and you will get 409 NameAlreadyExists